# Could not initialize class java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl when importing Gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-8

I'm trying to import my Gradle project into `Eclipse` but I'm encountering the error below when clicking 'Build Model'

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:112)
                at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not initialize class java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl
```

I'm using Eclipse Mars, Gradle 2.13, Gradle IDE Pack 3.7.x and JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

I've d to fixed the issue by installing a newer version of JDK 1.8. Possibly my existing version got corrupted.

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue. For corporate users, I have a feeling that background software updates installed a new version of the JRE, but not the JDK. Installing the latest JDK fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in my IntelliJ Id after adding the SQL plugin.
I did restart the IntelliJ and the issue got resolved(maybe JDK was not corrupted).